# Gitlab asks for fingerprint. What is it?

Tags: git, macos, ssh, gitlab

When I push to GitLab, it shows:
`Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])`
I choose fingerprint. But I do not know what it is.
Git asks me for a password
`git@nas.xxx.site's password:` 
So what is it???

on MacOS

Answer (score 1):

According **aeadedoyin** in [this question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/the-authenticity-of-host-can-t-be-established-not-new-machine-or-ssh-key) at DigitalOcean:

> So this is for any other person having the same issue.
> It’s quite straightforward:
>
> When this prompt is returned, it’s simply saying it doesn’t recognise this ip address i.e. it’s not part of your known_host.
>
> Copy the key provided here
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:stringoflettersandnumbers.
>
> And paste it where it’s asking for yes or no or fingerprint
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? SHA256:stringoflettersandnumbers.
>
> And hit enter. This will add the ip address to known_host then you can ssh into it, with cmd or bash or vscode remote ssh functionality

This means that you must copy the fingerprint key that appears a line before and paste it when the terminal prompts again.